# Qual é a diferença entre o JAVA WEB e o JAVA EE do NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

Qual é a diferença entre o tipo de projeto JAVA WEB e o JAVA EE do NetBeans?

Comment: https://netbeans.org/kb/trails/java-ee_pt_BR.html

Answer (score 4):

O Projeto Java Web no Netbeans, que tem o ícone de globinho, cria um container com duas pastas importantes: Páginas web, que guarda em geral arquivos jsps, htmls, css e javascript e a pasta Source packages que guarda em geral servlets ou arquivos de framework.

O projeto Java EE já tem uma estrutura diferente e é focado em EJB, tendo três divisões: O triângulo que é onde você vai gerenciar o projeto como um todo, o globinho que é o projeto web(igual ao projeto Java Web normal) e o feijãozinho que é a parte dos EJBs.

Caso queira aprender a criar um projeto Java EE utilizando páginas JSF, pode seguir este tutorial do Netbeans:
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/javaee-gettingstarted_pt_BR.html